# "Behind the scenes" difference between cornerRadius and bezierPathWithRoundedRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cornerradius

*Premise:* I am rounding the edges of a view with a solid background (to make something like an oval). There are many ways to do this, but the two most common I've see recommended are:

1) set the cornerRadius property on the view layer and bind the mask layer to the view layer bounds (through clipsToBounds or masksToBounds) (https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius)
ex:

```
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    view.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

2) create a Bezier Path with [bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii] and use it to create a mask layer which you set to the view's layer's mask. (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624368-bezierpathwithroundedrect)
ex:

```
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: view.bounds 
      byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners 
      cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    CAShapeLayer* maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

*Question:* Both ways work well for me and I see no significant performance of one over the other (admittedly, I'm not using it heavily). In which situations should I use a Bezier path over setting the corner radius (assuming the corner radii are equal)? Do these two methods to creating rounded edges do the same thing behind the scenes? Are there certain platforms that won't support both solutions?

Best Regards

Comment: You can refer this link: https://github.com/linkedin/LayoutKit/issues/78
Hope it gives you some lead.